# Sorting Models on the basis of count of its different associated models

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model School which has many Teachers and Students. Each Teacher and Student belongs to a school.

I want to sort(decreasing order) all records of School on basis of sum of teachers and students belongs to school using queries.

I am using below two queries to sort on the basis of number of teachers or number of students

```
School.joins(:teachers).group('schools.id').order('COUNT(teachers.id) DESC')
School.joins(:students).group('schools.id').order('COUNT(students.id) DESC')
```

Is there any way to write query for sorting on the basis of sum of teachers and students

Comment: I suggest looking into Rails counter_cache feature: https://www.rootstrap.com/blog/efficient-counter-caches/

Comment: But I am actually looking for query.

Comment: my rails knowledge is spotty these days but have you tried just literally combining the two like `School.joins(:students).joins(:teachers).group('schools.id').order('(COUNT(students.id)) + (COUNT(teachers.id)) DESC')`

Comment: When I try to get sum of teacher and students for each school records it shows different value.  This is the query I am using to get count School.joins(:students).joins(:teachers).group('schools.id').order('(COUNT(students.id)) + (COUNT(teachers.id)) DESC').count

Comment: With the `count` in the above query in the last comment what are you trying to get? It would return the count of schools. Also another way to do this could be: `School.joins(:students, :teachers).select('schools.*, (COUNT(students.id) + COUNT(teachers.id)) AS total_count').group('schools.id').order('total_count DESC')`

Comment: with `count` I am getting a hash where keys are school id and values are the sum of teachers.count  + student.count to the respective school. But the value of hash are wrong